# Django admin broken template when using uwsgi

Tags: python, django, admin, uwsgi

When I start my application using `python3 manage.py run server 0.0.0.0:8000` I can access Django admin just fine.
However, when I run it using `uwsgi` the Django admin template is broken. The application works fine, but the website is displayed as simple text, no templates at all. For instance, here's the login page:
[image]

How can I fix this?
This my `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir               = ./src
http                = :8000
enable-threads      = true
#harakiri           = 300
master              = true
module              = config.wsgi:application
#processes           = $(UWSGI_PROCESSES)
#threads             = $(UWSGI_THREADS)
#max-worker-lifetime = $(UWSGI_MAX_WORKER_LIFE)
workers             = 32
thunder-lock        = true
vacuum              = true
workdir             = ./src
add-header          = Connection: Keep-Alive
http-keepalive      = 65000
max-requests        = 50000
max-requests-delta  = 10000
max-worker-lifetime = 360000000000         ; Restart workers after this many seconds
reload-on-rss = 2048                 ; Restart workers after this much resident memory
worker-reload-mercy = 60             ; How long to wait before forcefully killing workers
# Increment the timeout to reach the target app.
# http-timeout      = 60
lazy-apps           = true
single-interpreter = true
ignore-sigpipe      = true
ignore-write-errors = true
http-auto-chunked   = true
disable-write-exception = true
```

This is the `settings.py` for my app:

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

import socket

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = (Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / '..').resolve()


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-yn8)g036-ul$ge)b=$)*mn0k$%_xl0f(_*)24j)r=w5o%v)(2z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
    'host.docker.internal',
    '3.236.90.54',
    socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://35.153.126.53:8000',
)

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 3rd party
    'corsheaders',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_filters',
    'drf_yasg',
    'polymorphic',
    'rest_framework',
    # Local
    'vehicles',
    'api'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.history.HistoryPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'data/django/db.sqlite3',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': None
    }
}

# Cache
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/home/ubuntu/pycharm/projects/ai-datasets/django_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': None,  # never expires
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 1e6
        }
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/django/media/')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# REST_FRAMEWORK
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}

# LOGGING = {
#     'version': 1,
#     'disable_existing_loggers': False,
#     'handlers': {
#         'console': {
#             'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
#         },
#     },
#     'root': {
#         'handlers': ['console'],
#         'level': 'WARNING',
#     },
#     'loggers': {
#         'django': {
#             'handlers': ['console'],
#             'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
#             'propagate': False,
#         },
#     },
# }
#
# LOGGING['loggers']['django.db.backends'] = {
#     'handlers': ['console'],
#     'level': 'DEBUG',
# }
```

Also, here's the console errors that I see in Safari:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (base.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (nav_sidebar.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (nav_sidebar.js, line 0)
[Error] Refused to execute http://myip...:8000/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.generateKey')
    promiseEmptyOnRejected (content-script.js:75:780)
    promiseReactionJob
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (login.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (responsive.css, line 0)
```

EDIT: here's the network calls for the css/js files as requested

[image]

Comment: Check the networks calls for any css/js files.

Comment: I added a screenshot in the post above. Do you think it's fine? Why are they red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up NGINX and it helped to solve the issue. However, I still don't know what caused the issue in the first place, and how to solve it without NGINX.